# How to add extra button to GridView?

Tags: android, gridview

Within a `LinearLayout` I have a `GridView` which, when running the app, places 4 elements on the screen (3 in first row, 1 in second row, plenty of space on the screen). At the bottom of the page I want to add an Extra button, independent of the `GridView`. I have tried the following:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/select_route"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.impyiablue.checkpoint.SelectRoute">

    <GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/selectroute_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:columnWidth="90dp"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:gravity="center"
        />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="9dp"
        android:paddingRight="9dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <Button android:id="@+id/finalCancel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/check_redo"
            android:background="@color/colorUndo"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:padding="25dip"
            android:layout_marginBottom="50dp" />

    </LinearLayout>>
</LinearLayout>
```

But I do not see an extra button anywhere? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You don't need to enclose the Button in another LinearLayout. Try keeping your design as flat as possible, for performance sake. That LinearLayout, by the way, is abusively using the `layout_weight` property.

Comment: The inner linear layout is unnecessary!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
android:layout_weight="0.4"
android:layout_height="0dp"
```

to your `GridView`

and

```
android:layout_weight="0.1"
android:layout_height="0dp"
```

to the `LinearLayout` which is below the `GridView`